# Android App Rejection - Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, user-permissions

Issue found: Invalid or inaccurate Permission Form

Your app uses sensitive permissions that require a Permissions Declaration Form to be properly submitted. Please check that you have accurately submitted the form in the Play console and that you are only using the allowed permission for your declared use case(s).

This is the mail I am getting from the Google Play console when the app is rejected.

Steps that are already taken:-

1. I have tried to cross-verify the reference links provided in the email and have also removed the Sensitive permission that we were using and still the application is not getting approved and getting the same email while the rejection.
2. Our application has been rejected multiple times.  Instead of submitting the app again, we have used “Sensitive Permissions Checklist” document to prepare a check list in Excel, listing out what we do to comply with the checklist.  To this end, we have copied and pasted each section of checklist in the Excel, and provided information on which permissions apply to us and how we are handling these in our app and also addressed areas that do not apply to us.

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: Have you crosscheck what are the permission have you used in your app with the new policies like that google send through email? Also play store may updated their policy, so kindly read it before submitting app again in play console.

Comment: This is the mail I am getting from the Google Play console when the app is rejected. I have tried to cross-verify the reference links provided in the email. and have also removed the Sensitive permission that we were using and still the application is not getting approved and getting the same email while the rejection.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Team trying to be Apple Store but keep sh*ting. Recently they reject without even reviewing the app and It is really annoying.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely a library your using is causing this, I recommend adding the permissions and data collected by this or these libraries.
here is a [table of the privacy form for most common libraries](https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report/blob/main/Android%20App%20-%20SDK%20Privacy%20Report.csv)